# Does the standard guarantee, that std::string::resize will not do reallocate memory, if the new size is less than or equal to as the old one?

Tags: c++, string, resize

I need to frequently make a string empty and then append some chars into it.
std::string::clear() may realloc
Does std::string::resize(0) do realloc? The standard's words didn't garentee any about it.

Comment: Take this as you will: `If n <= size(), the function replaces the string designated by *this with a string of length n
whose elements are a copy of the initial elements of the original string designated by *this.`

Comment: You asked if the standard guaranteed it but then stated that it doesn't. If it is left to the individual library implementations you will just have to take a look at the source.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best possible answer to this is the "Notes" section at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear.

> Unlike for std::vector::clear, the C++ standard does not explicitly require that capacity is unchanged by this function, but existing implementations do not change capacity.

And if the capacity is unchanged, that would almost certainly mean that no allocation or freeing functions are called. That's probably the best you can do, short of looking at each and every implementation you care about.